# Windows 3.11 on ESXi4 - network not working

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi

I migrated a VM running Windows 3.11 for Workgroups from VMware Workstation to ESXi 4.0U1 and the networking inside the guest machine has stopped working.

I reinstalled the network card driver, and changed the VM to use a static IP but it doesn't help.

Pls help me.

Comment: WOW, there's a flashback.

Curious though, what is the ESXi server hardware? and I have good reason to think the driver will not work, hopefully you have not blown away your original 3.11 machine, if you actually need it.

Answer (score 1):

Which network card are you using for the VM?  I believe ESXi likes to emulate a e1000 but in older Vmware Workstation VMs you needed to use a pcnet32.  You mention that you reinstalled the driver, which driver did you use?  You may need to download a different NDIS 2 driver, or switch the adapter type in the VM configuration.